# Tabs and fragments

Tags: android, tabs

I am using the library `com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1` to make an Android app using bottom tabs. The problem is that in his `github`, there is no actual example on how tabs work with fragments. I have tried to work my way around it but to no success. Here is the code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.three_buttons_activity);

    BottomBar bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.three_buttons_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.recent_item:
                    //Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Recent Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.favorite_item:
                    //Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Favorite Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.location_item:
                    //Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#FFFFFF");
}
}
```

I wanted to have for example if I choose "recent item" it will go to recent item tab and do whatever on that tab but it doesn't happen to me.

If any of you have a good suggestion and example on how to do it right, I will really appreciate it..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this bottom bar over a year ago. this is how i added the fragments.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_three_buttons);


         // ************* Setting Up The Bottom Bar ************ //

        BottomBar bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        bottomBar.noTabletGoodness();

        // *********** Adding Item Fragments to the bottom Bar ************ //

        bottomBar.setFragmentItems(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragmentContainer,
                new BottomBarFragment(ProfileFragment.newInstance("Content For Profile"), R.drawable.ic_profile, "Profile"),
        new BottomBarFragment(MessagesFragment.newInstance(), R.drawable.ic_chat, "Messages"));
       // bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#009688");
        bottomBar.setActiveTabColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    }
```

And one of the **Fragment Class:**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
  public static ProfileFragment newInstance(String text) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(STARTING_TEXT, text);
        ProfileFragment homeFragment = new ProfileFragment();
        homeFragment.setArguments(args);
        return homeFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_profile_fragment, container, false);

                // do your stuff

        return rootView;
}
```

Comment: M.Waqas Pervez one more thing. I tried to put listview and a textview on one of my fragment_layout.xml but when i tried to run it, it always comes out as blank. I have put this code on onCreateView on the fragment TextView tvTest = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        tvTest.setText(STARTING_TEXT); but nothing happens.